# Has anyone tried Ubuntu 22.04.2 on Acer Swift X?

Tags: drivers, nvidia, acer

I'm going to install Ubuntu Jammy Jellyfish on my new laptop, and I need to know if someone has had problems with that distribution on that PC

Information about this pc:

- model: Swift SFX14-42G
- processor: AMD Ryzen 7 5825U
- graphics: NVIDIA GeForce RTX 3050

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Will my device work with Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/986878/will-my-device-work-with-ubuntu)

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you try yourself with a live system? You only need to boot into a USB stick with that version on it and check if all components are working (which is very likely).